# remove cookies and other site data for chrome without using normal UI

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser-cache

Google Chrome is causing all sorts of issues for my laptop at the moment. Cannot access many websites (youtube, etc.) even though they are accessible via firefox and other browsers. Many of the proposed solutions involve clearing cache / cookies, however we cannot clear cookies:

[image]

From this page, it hangs indefinitely when we click Clear data, and this is the case even if we narrow the window from All Time down to 1 hour. Is there another way to clear cookies from chrome? Can I find & delete them in finder? Something to type into terminal to clear the cookies? We have already tried uninstalling & reinstalling Chrome, with no luck. On a fairly new macbook pro.